# Why is VB6 FlexGrid throwing a run-time error 381 'Subscript out of range'?

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

I don't really know much about `VB6`, but I am currently having a problem with double clicking a cell in a `FlexGrid`. I can see that this is a popular question that has been asked many times, but most of the users are looping around the grid. Mine is more simple, but yet it crashes.

The grid has 3 rows and 3 columns.
When double clicking on any of the columns from the first row, it works fine. But when I get to the others, it throws an error. The error says:

> Run-time error '381':
>
> Subscript out of range.

It currently crashes at the following line, where the row is 2 and the col is 3:

```
TextMatrix = myFlexGrid.TextMatrix(row, col)
```

I am just wondering why it crashes when the indexes of the row and the column are fine. I thought that it might be zero-based but when clicking the third cell on the first row, it works fine.

Is there a way to see the contents of the grid in the debugger (Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0)?

Comment: Could we see a bit more of the function being called here? The origin of all the variables isn't clear.

Comment: @CMaster it is really difficult for me to post some code, as everything is split around and it is a part of a huge project. But perhaps I have to change the title to "how to see the contents of the grid". Because, as I said the row and the col are fine. I guess, for some reason, the grid just doesn't have all the rows, besides the first one.

Comment: Is the FlexGrid_dblclick() Function really that long that you can't show us it? If there's big chunks of irrelevant logic, then feel free to say <more code here>

Comment: The primary issue is it's not clear where "row" and "col" above are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows and cols of a flexgrid are indeed 0 based. However, if you take the FlexGrid.Row and FlexGrid.Col values, then they are always going to be in range, as these denote the currently selected cell. Something like this should work:

```
private sub FlexGrid_DblClick()
    dim CellContents as string
    with FlexGrid
        CellContents = .TextMatrix(.Row,.Col)
    end with
end sub
```

Although in the case that you are interested in the selected cell, you can always just use

`CellContents = FlexGrid.Text`

You can get a lot of info on any of your controls (or variables) at run time using the "Locals" window of the IDE, while execution is paused. Unfortunatley, that doesn't seem to include the cell contents of a flexgrid. You can always use the Immediate window to feel around the grid though, with lines like `? FlexGrid.TextMatrix(0,2)` to find the values and the limits that cause errors.

Comment: Thanks about the detailed answer! What do the "." in front of row and col mean? In my case, I don't have them.

Comment: That's because I used "with" above - the . means "append whatever is in the with statement". If I hadn't used with, then I'd have to have written `CellContents = FlexGrid.TextMatrix(FlexGrid.Row, FlexGrid.Col) `If you are just using "row" and "col" and not giving them values earlier, then you've got some uninitalized variables there, could be probelmatic - hence why I wanted to see more of your function.

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is related to the values you were putting in your `row` and `col` variables. That is why I asked to see the full function (note, not the full form)